# Use objC in swift unit test target

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode7

I am trying to use objC code in my unit test target which is swift. But when looking at Swift Compiler section there is no bridging header setup. Any ideas why is that missing? Project was created for objC. Then I added swift unit test target.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when having objc project you have to create test target in objc as well. Adding swift file inside will trigger bridging-header dialog and create Swift Compiler section along with bridging-header row.